# Poison : unable to encode value

Tags: json, elixir, ecto, elixir-poison

I am not able to encode values which I am getting from Ecto query result  Poison encode method

**Controller code:**

```
def companies(conn, params) do
    companies = Repo.all(
      from(
        c in Company,
        select: {c.name, c.uid},
        limit: 20
      )
    ) 

    conn
    |> put_resp_header("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    |> send_resp(200, Poison.encode!(companies, pretty: true))
end
```

**Template code :**

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <%= label f, :company_id, class: "control-label" %>
  <%= select f, :company_id, @companies, class: "form-control"%>
<%= error_tag f, :company_id %>
```

**Error message:**

```
Request: GET /companies
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {"Loews Corporation", 1000285930}
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:383: Poison.Encoder.Any.encode/2
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:268: anonymous fn/4 in Poison.Encoder.List.encode/3
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:269: Poison.Encoder.List."-encode/3-lists^foldr/2-0-"/3
        (poison) lib/poison/encoder.ex:269: Poison.Encoder.List.encode/3
        (poison) lib/poison.ex:41: Poison.encode!/2
```

Comment: I would think it is problem of the tuple you are returning, have you tried with encoding a map instead? something like: `select: %{name: c.name, uid: c.uid}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples can't be encoded to JSON values by Poison. If you want `[{name: ..., uid: ...}, {name: ..., uid: ...}]` in the resulting JSON, you can use `map()` or a map literal in `select` in the query:

```
select: map(c, [:name, :uid])
```

or

```
select: %{name: c.name, uid: c.uid}
```

Comment: It worked but any idea about the error: protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for %{name:

Comment: <div class="form-group row">
    <%= label f, :company_id, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= select f, :company_id, @companies, class: "form-control"%>
    <%= error_tag f, :company_id %>
  </div>

Comment: In the code in the question you're sending a JSON response. Where are you calling this template code from?

Comment: So on the same form, I am calling autocomplete search <div class="form-group row">
  <%= label(:user, :country, "Country", class: "control-label col-sm-2") %>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= awesomplete(:user, :country, 
                      [class: "form-control"], 
                      [ url: rule_set_path(@conn, :companies), 
                        loadall: true, 
                        prepop: true,
                        minChars: 1, 
                        maxItems: 8, 
                        value: "name"
                      ]) %>
  </div>

Comment: It worked after I made changes to form like <%= select f, :company_id, @companies |> Enum.map(&{&1.name, &1.uid}), class: "form-control"%>

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the @Dogbert’s answer: you also might produce a JSON object by producing a `map` out of what `Ecto` returned manually:

```
companies =
  from(c in Company, select: {c.name, c.uid}, limit: 20)
  |> Repo.all()     # returning list of tuples
  |> Enum.into(%{}) # this

#⇒ %{"Loews Corporation" => 1000285930, "Foo" => 1, "Bar" => 2}
```

Maps might be encoded to JSON with `Poison`, producing JS objects.